# "$nid" for individual pages not working

Tags: theming, nodes, media

```
<?php 
  $nid = arg(1);
  $arg0 = arg(0);
  if(isset($nid) && is_numeric($nid) && isset($arg0) && $arg0 == 'node') {
    $node = node_load($nid);
  }
  $theme_img = file_create_url($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
  if(isset($theme_img)) {
    // print styled image
    print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'page_theme')); 
  }  
?>
```

I am using the above code to load styled image (from node 6) in page.tpl file. This is working fine in all the pages but when I am trying to load images from individual images by using '$nid' it is not working. 
I don't understand what I made mistake in code due to which I couldn't get the value of '$nid'. Please help.

Comment: Why are expecting $nid as a global variable or if not your above code is not showing how you are using $nid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to replace the "6" by the current nid of the page.
If so, you could use this code to get the nid of the current page:

```
$nid = arg(1);
$arg0 = arg(0)
if(isset($nid) && is_numeric($nid) && isset($arg0) && $arg0 == 'node') {
  //If you're using devel
  dsm($nid);
  //If not
  drupal_set_message($nid);
}
```

But as stated by Jeet, if the code is specific to one content type, you should do this in a node--mycontenttype.tpl.php and not in the page.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks Matt. Due to your code I could get the node ID but getting some error on node page which doesn't have field "field_page_cover_image". Please see the updated code above.

Comment: The modified code works fine in pages which has images uploaded. It doesn't work on pages which doesn't have image field or uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to edit/override node template, it is suggested to place your changes into `node.tpl.php` where you will get `$nid` as out of the box. `page.tpl.php` will not give you node variables by default.

If you still you want to get your code on `page.tpl.php` you can get `$nid` from url like `arg(1)`.

Let me know if I miss anything!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $nid variable in your page.tpl.php, you can add that variable to be available in the page.tpl.php by implementing hook_preprocess_page() in your theme's template.php. In your implementation of the hook_preprocess_page() you have to add a key 'nid' to the $variables array. Eg: `$variables['nid'] = the_nid_you_want;`. After you have saved the changes, clear the Drupal cache and the $nid variable will now be available in your page.tpl.php